# Netezza range of dates

Tags: sql, netezza

I want to solve an issue to reduce manual labour in a specific query. Hope i can phrase this correctly to be understood.

In Netezza, I want to generate a (date ) value and run the query for every different value specified.
What I want to do is **replace all the unions into one query**.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT a.x) AS NO_OF_X, a.column1, 'JAN 2019'
FROM my_table a
WHERE 1=1  
AND current_date BETWEEN a.date_from and a.date_to

GROUP BY 2,3  

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT a.x) AS NO_OF_X, a.column1, 'DEC 2018'
FROM my_table a
WHERE 1=1  
AND '2018-12-31' BETWEEN a.date_from and a.date_to
GROUP BY 2,3

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT a.x) AS NO_OF_X, a.column1, 'NOV 2018'
FROM my_table a
WHERE 1=1  
AND '2018-11-30' BETWEEN a.date_from and a.date_to
GROUP BY 2,3
```

What i want to do is something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT a.x) AS NO_OF_X, a.column1, last_day( date ) as "MONTH"
FROM my_table a
WHERE 1=1  
AND /*run the query for all last_days in a range */ 
GROUP BY 2,3
```

Is this possible? Tried to make a CTE but it is really important to get results for each specific last day of month, because our datawarehouse is designed, to store different time slices for each transaction etc. And i want to get only transactions with time slices on a specific last_day().

Cheers.

Comment: WHy do you add `WHERE 1=1 ` to your query?

Comment: Old habbit. I use it because of two things ... 1) Because its easier to start with 1=1 ( always true ) so I can start listing all other  conditions with "AND" ( and my brain process them faster :) ). 2) For intentionaly failing queries when writing stored procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a list of dates.  Here is one method:

```
select to_char(m.dte, 'MMM YYYY'), t.column1,
       count(distinct a.x) AS NO_OF_X
from (SELECT current_date as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 day' as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 day' - interval '1 month' as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 day' - interval '2 month' as dte
      ) m left join
      my_table t
where m.dte between t.date_from and t.date_to
group by to_char(m.dte, 'MMM YYYY'), t.column1
order by min(m.dte), t.column1;
```

Comment: THIS IS the correct answer! Thank you very much ( changed a few aliases to match ), but I managed to make it work. Also gives me an idea, to implement this in some other project im working on!